# Name and information about this graph

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

A certain family of graphs crossed my way while performing some quantum mechanics calculations, and I am very curious whether they have been studied in mathematics before in a different context.

Also I would be interested in properties of these graphs, other that they are planar multi-graphs.

Here are the examples. Let's start with the simplest example. It is a complete $K_4$ graph with one additional edge, making one edge a double-edge (let's call it *Wing$_1$ graph*, for reasons that become clear soon):

[image: Wing-1]

Now here the second member of the family. These are two $K_4$ graphs which are connected at two vertices (let's call it *Wing$_2$ graph*):

[image: Wing-2]

And now we add more and more $K_4$ graphs to the graph, but without increasing the number of edges between the central two vertices. Here is an example of the *Wing$_5$* graph (from three different perspectives).

[image: Wing-5]

I am very curious whether this is family has been studied before, whether it belongs to a larger class of graphs with certain properties etc.
(Also as a sort of meta-question: Is there a way how to find names of graphs in a simple way? Such as a OEIS for graphs?)

Comment: House of Graphs (https://hog.grinvin.org/) can occasionally help you with this sort of question, but it is not nearly as large or well-established as the OEIS and it does not deal with multigraphs.

Comment: http://www.graphclasses.org/ has a rather extensive list of named graph classes; it is more browsable and less searchable than HoG and it also lacks multigraphs.

Comment: Because the number of possible variations explodes when multiple edges are allowed, you're unlikely to find much (if any) previous research on such a specific class as you've defined.

Comment: Off-the-cuff naming idea: (generally) multi-bound n-page clique-book; (specific to your case) 2-bound n-page K_4-book.

Comment: Personally I think that you cannot do better in this case than use the advice already given (essentially: to look at the much-studied class of 'book graphs', which your graphs are of course *not* isomorphic to), and for each and every result known about 'book graphs' investigate if and how the result changes on account of the one and only *multiedge* at the 'spine' of the book; incidentally,  such a multiedge in graph theory is called a http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DipoleGraph.html, while in theoretical physics I have repeatedly read it referred to as 'banana graph'.

Comment: Dear R.Ror and Peter - thank you both very much for your reply. The connection to book graphs is very interesting - now i have a place where i can connect to. I think the information given about the book graph is the best I would have expected. How about you transform your comment to an answer which i can accept? Thanks again.

Comment: @D.Ror.: re "your comment to an answer which i can accept": this, if at all, is for D. Ror. to do, because, while I would have mentioned this too, they said "book" first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of simple graphs, you could search the House of Graphs  (http://hog.grinvin.org) or browse the Information System on Graph Classes and their Inclusions (http://www.graphclasses.org).

Because the number of possible variations explodes when multiple edges are allowed, you're unlikely to find much (if any) previous research on such a specific class as you've defined. Here's one naming idea:

- (in general) multi-spine clique-book;
- (specific to your case) n-page 2-spine K_4-book.

Peter Heinig (2018-03-01, 18L15:20Z) suggested "for each and every result known about *book graphs*" (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BookGraph.html), to "investigate if and how the result changes on account of one and only [one] multiedge at the *spine* of the book." He noted that a multiedge is sometimes called a *dipole* (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DipoleGraph.html) or, in theoretical physics, a *banana graph*.